# what is the difference between LAMPP and METEOR

Tags: javascript, meteor

Can anybody explain me what is the difference between LAMPP and METEOR js framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're completely different.

Comment: I want to know how meteor server differ from apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a big difference between the two.

**LAMP**:

- This is a stack that originally (and still largely) stands for Linux Apache MySQL and PHP
- The alternative of windows is called WAMP.
- The linux part is the system the stack is running on; Apache is a server system where you can store and access your websites and apps; MySQL is the type of database(Relational Database); PHP is the server-side language you use to create these dynamic sites (you can also use python or perl).
- The community is much larger and you can get support everywhere as it has been around longer than Meteor
- If you run a linux os, you can literally download the apache server and host it on your computer see: http://httpd.apache.org/

**Meteorjs**

- Meteor is a full stack platform that allows you to write all your code in Javascript. This means you can write the front end in Javascript, then turn around and also write the server/backend using the same JavaScript! Literally write once, run everywhere
- Meteor allows you to write an app in very short amount of time as you are using just javascript.
  -What really makes Meteor stand out is their "realtime" way of doing things. With mete0r, everything is reactive. When a change happens in the server, it is immediately reflected on the front-end without refresh or waiting at all!
- Meteor apps come with Mongodb (NoSQL) already set up as your database system as opposed to MySQL used by LAMP. Meteor goes the extra mile by also creating a small database in the front end of your app and whatever changes you make are performed in this mini-mongo database which automagically synchronizes with the server and updates it. METEOR DOES ALL THIS FOR YOU.
  -Learn more at https://www.meteor.com/ and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpQTPWvD6HA offers a great intro.